# How to Customize my ListView by adding an image on left

Tags: image, list, view

I just would to customize my ListView with an image on the left

```
package com.project.test;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import android.R.id;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ContactUs extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    ListView list;
     LazyAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactsList;

    // url to get all contacts list
    private static String url_all_contacts = "http://10.0.2.2/test/get_all_staff.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_CONTACT = "contacts";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_IMAGE = "image";

    static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
    static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;
    ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_staff);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        contactsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading contacts in Background Thread
        new LoadAllcontacts().execute();
            //list = getListView();
        // Get listview
        //ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        /*
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        GetAllStaffDetails.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });
        */
    }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllcontacts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ContactUs.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading contacts. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All contacts from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_contacts, "GET",
                    params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All contacts: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // contacts found
                    // Getting Array of contacts
                    contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACT);

                    // looping through All contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String image = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        contactsList.add(map);
                    }
                    //list = (ListView)findViewById(id.list);
                    //list.setAdapter(contactsList);


                } else {
                    // no contacts found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            NewProductActivity.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all contacts
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                       //adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, contactsList);

                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ContactUs.this,
                            contactsList, R.layout.list_row, new String[] {
                                    TAG_PID, TAG_NAME }, new int[] { R.id.pid,
                                    R.id.name });

                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

This is the code am using right now, but I had some difficulties in how to retrieve an image from data base using JSON then insert the image to the ListView. So any help please ??

Answer (score 0):

Provide more details if you wonna get answer.

From which field you wonna get image? This is an url, filesystem ref or may be base64 data, or...

In your layout (`R.layout.list_row`) you should have an ImageView into which you can set any kind of `Drawable` object to be displayed.

And remove `runOnUiThread` call, because in `onPostExecute` you already on UI thread.

Comment: I wanna get the image from website database (working on local server right now ). I already set the the list_row.xml file and it's ready and thank you for your notice.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question:
What `String image = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);` this variable contains?

Comment: its supposed to be the holder for url of the image. I was trying to retrieve the url from database then display the image through it.

Comment: here is a ready answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android